# How to change edge thickness in D3.js?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Code example https://jsfiddle.net/greggyNapalm/xtg7t5ch/
I want to control edge thickness with `weight` attr.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try adding:

```
 .attr("style", function(d) { return ("stroke-width:" + d.weight + "px;");})
```

Answer (score 0):

First remove this line from your `path.link` class from CSS file.

```
stroke-width: 2.0px;
```

Then, in your java-script file add following line in `path` variable.

```
.attr("stroke-width", function(d) { return (d.weight); })
```

---

Another method by which you can override the style property which @drone6502 suggested, is to add `style` attribute. Here, no need to remove `stroke-width` from CSS.

```
.attr("style", function(d) { return ("stroke-width:" + d.weight + "px;");})
```